# Converting height given in meters to feet and inches?

Tags: python

Here is the problem:

> Given that 1 foot = .3048 meters, write a Python script that will
>   convert a height given meters to a height given in feet and inches.

I looked over the notes the professor gave that day and I am following each step but my program just doesn't seem to work correctly. Here's what I have:

```
print("This program will convert a height given meters to a height given in feet and inches.")
meters = float(input("Enter height in meters:"))
meters_in_ft = meters // .3048
meters_in_in = meters_in_ft % 12
print("The height is", meters_in_ft,"feet and",meters_in_in, "inches")
```

When I run the program and type certain meters I will get it correct in feet, but a lot of times the measurement in inches is wrong.

Comment: Can you be more specific than *"is wrong"*? What are your inputs, and the expected and actual outputs?

Comment: As per Google 1 meter = 3.2808399 feet (3 feet 3⅜ inches)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get the inches portion from meters, you need to get the decimal portion of `meters / .3048` by using `% 1`. Then you can convert that to inches by multiplying by `12`.

```
inches = meters / .3048 % 1 * 12
```

Comment: Thank you so much this ended up working. I will keep practicing to make sure I can use this function properly. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer for other visitors from a Google search:

**Meters to feet + inches**

```
feet = int(meters / 0.3048)
inches = meters / 0.3048 % 1 * 12
inches = round(inches)  #optional
```

**Feet and inches to meters**

```
meters = (feet + inches/12)*0.3048
```